# How can I populate nested Schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to populate a field in my SCHEMA.
This is my Schema

This is the GameSchema

```
const GameSchema = new Schema({
    GameType: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    Schedule: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    Status: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    ResultId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Results'},
    BettingStatus: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    AdditionalDetails: [{
        Team1: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SportsTeam'},
        Team2: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SportsTeam'},
    }]
}, {timestamps: true});
```

```
const SportsTeamSchema = new Schema({
    TeamName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Acronym: {
        type: String,
    },
    ImageLink: {
        type: String,
    }
}, {timestamps: true});
```

This is my Second Schema..
What I wanted to do is Populate the *AdditionalDetails *Schema.
This is my code looks so far which isn't working.

```
        try {
            Games.find()
                    .populate({
                        path: 'AdditionalDetails',
                        populate: {
                           path: 'Team1',
                           model: 'SportsTeam'
                        }
                     })
                    .exec((err, result) => {
                        console.log(result)
                        res.send(result)
                    })
        } catch (error) {
            errorlogger(error, `Ag Fetch Schedule ${req.username}`);
            res.status(500).send('Unable to process Request');
        }
```

I don't get any error. But always got empty results

To populate the AdditionalDetails Field

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below as it works for me.

```
try {
    Games.find()
        .populate('AdditionalDetails.Team1')
        .exec((err, result) => {
            console.log(result)
            res.send(result)
        })
} catch (error) {
    errorlogger(error, `Ag Fetch Schedule ${req.username}`);
    res.status(500).send('Unable to process Request');
}
```